# Detect Single Slash in URL apache

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I'm having problem in detecting the single slash only in the URL, the URL which I want is

http://sitename.com/username

through this Rewrite RULE i can capture the username but its also valid for leading slashes as well which is unwanted.

```
RewriteRule ([A-Za-z0-9]+){0,1}$ index.php?c=profile&val=$1 [NC,L]
```

`^` starting sign returns nothing so I've removed it, Right now I'm testing it over local host so my test url is

```
http://localhost/projectname/username
```

on server its

```
http://sitename.com/username
```

this is my complete .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/

RewriteCond $1 !^(maintainance\.php|index\.php|files|images|robots\.txt|css|js)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+){0,1}$ index.php?c=profile&val=$1 [NC,L]
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I capture the single slash username throught rewriteRule

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just a remark, since it appears you did not fully understand how regular expressions work: You wrote: "`^` starting sign returns nothing so I've removed it"... that character is not meant to "return anything". It anchors the pattern to the beginning of the input string to make sure there is no garbage. Without that character your pattern is blind and just ignores leading garbage which most likely is not what you want.

Comment: @arkascha thanks, I understand ^ represent the starting sign, I tried to put it to restrict the RE to single slash, so anything with start to end validating my RE should come into this rule

Comment: Ok, then you should re-read the documentation of .htaccess style url rewriting. There will _never_ be a leading slash in the input string you try to evaluate. You can only do such thing when you use rewriting in the central http server configuration, which is the preferred way over .htaccess style files, actually.

Comment: Oh, and I want to repeat that warning: the pattern withoout leading `^` will be blind (ignore) garbage leading characters currently. This is _not_ what you want.

Comment: @arkascha ok I've put the starting sign,  ^([A-Za-z0-9/]+){0,1}$ & ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$  these are valid RE for somthing like /username, but its also not working in rewrite url

Comment: Didn't you read my comment? There will _never_ be a leading slash in the string you process. This is because you are using rewriting inside .htaccess style files. A leading slash does not make sense there, since it is a relative processing you do. Read the excellent documentation!

Comment: ok thanks I'll read the docs, for now it worked for my me, may be its not good solution but its working fine  RewriteRule php/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$

Comment: Strange... pattern `php/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$` will certainly _not_ match the input `/username` which you gave as an example... But ok...

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following htaccess script. In `val` you can get the url values.exploding by `/` you can get the user name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectname/
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+){0,1}$ index.php?c=profile&val=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks Kalai, but I 've more rules below it, so I want rule it to stop going below if it get the single slash URL, is that possible

Comment: what I want is if its single slash it come under this rule and will break with [NC,L] tags, else it would valid the remaining Rewrite rules they are all of double slash validators, here they are RewriteRule page/new_page/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?c=page&m=new_page&title=$1&pageno=$2
RewriteRule page1/new_page1/(.*).html$ index.php?c=page1&m=new_page1&title=$1